# Adding sections (anchors) to a fluid menu in typo3 with bootstrap_package

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I would like to have a menu mixing pages and sections from current page.
For example on page1:

- section1_from_page1
- section2_from_page1
- page2
- page3

And on page2:

- section1_from_page2
- page1
- page3

Until now, all I'm able to do is to build a new section menu with TypoScript :

```
lib.sectionnavigation = HMENU
lib.sectionnavigation {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        sectionIndex = 1
        sectionIndex.type = header
        sectionIndex.useColPos = -1
        NO {
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            linkWrap = <span> | </span> <span class="bar"></span>
            allWrap = <li> | </li>
            allWrap.insertData = 1
        }
    }
    special = list
    special.value.data = page:uid
}
```

And then add this menu in the Main.html partials from bootstrap_package, with `f:cObject` :

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.sectionnavigation" />
```

However, that means that I have to maintain "format" (`<li><span>...</span><span class="bar"></span></li>`) in both the TypoScript and the *Main.html* partial which is not convenient.
For example, if I change the menu so that I don't need the bar class span, I'll have to update the partial and the TypoScript!

From what I've understood, bootstrap_package defines the main menu in setup.txt:

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
10 {
    levels = 2
    includeSpacer = 1
    as = mainnavigation
}
```

And then used this in the *Main.html* partial:

```
<f:for each="{mainnavigation}" as="mainnavigationItem">
```

My first plan was to try to built an new array (similar to the one in `{mainnavigation}`) using TypoScript but I couldn't find a way!
I also tried to use a MenuProcessor but didn't succeed either.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the possibility to identify the current page in typoscript menus with the option to replace the complete rendering for a menu item.

The rendering for current page in a menu can be defined with `ACT` or `CUR`  (`ACT` identifies all pages in the root line: current page, parent, grand parent, ...). In your case it may not differ, but you might play it safe:

```
lib.MainMenu = HMENU
lib.MainMenu {
   wrap = <ul class="nav">|</ul>
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
      NO {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li><span> | </span> <span class="bar"></span></li>
      }
      CUR = 1 
      CUR.doNotShowLink = 1
      // insert your section menu here:  
      CUR.before.cObject < lib.sectionnavigation
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip.
Are you suggesting to replace the MenuProcessor with this method in order to have all the html in TypoScript?

Comment: I'm old school and do my menus completely in typoscript. And I have some concepts for my typoscript: everything I need to copy I define as `temp.*` (this will be removed before page rendering) and all I need in every page I define as variables for the fluid-template (as little `<f:cObject ...>` as possible in the fluids). so for this attempt I would have two temp-objects (`temp.MainMenu` using `temp.sectionnavigation`, and then the definition of the fluid variable: `MainMenu < temp.MainMenu`)

Comment: Ok, I got the idea and will keep the old school way in mind : that might be easier to maintain actually!